# Cycling Through Possible Matrixes MatLab

Tags: matlab, matrix, combinations

I'm trying to write a program to check the results of all possible combinations of **5** separate **5x5** matrices, where each element in all the matrices are booleans. However, my problem is I can't figure out a way to cause the matrices to check through every combination.

Illustrating what I would like to happen for a **2x2** matrix. I want my program to produce the matrix as follow:

```
(1) [0 0;0 0] 
(2) [1 0;0 0] 
(3) [1 1;0 0]
(4) [1 1;1 0]
(5) [1 1;1 1]
(6) [1 0;0 1]
(7) [1 1;0 1]
…
```

and so on until every possible matrix has been done. How I may achieve this, so that I do some operation with every one of these matrix combinations?

(I realise this will probably take an impossibly long time to completely cycle through **5  5x5** matrices, however I also wish to do it for smaller matrices (**3 3x3's**) and I would also like to just leave it running as long as possible to check through as many possible **5 5x5's** and seeing, out of the ones I've checked, which is the best result.)

Comment: Can you provide any code for what you've tried so far?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea where to even start on it, I've made 5 matrices as such: 

    pos1=[p111 p112 p113 p114 p115;p121 p122 p123 p124 p125;p131 p132 p133 p134 p135;p141 p142 p143 p144 p145;p151 p152 p153 p154 p155]<br/>

(Continued for 4 more matrices) And it to go through every combination of each of the elements, but I have no idea how to make it do so.
<br/>
I'm also not sure how to format properly on this website, sorry.

I've also just realised that there are probably more combinations than it would be reasonable to go through in 5 5x5s, however I also wish to do it for 3 3x3s.

Comment: See the help below the **Add Comment** button x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as you can see, you have several combinations of a zero matrix you want to add a one, right?

We could say that you have the following possible combinations you want to add a one. For the 2 dimensional case:

```
addOnes =

   Empty matrix: 1-by-0


onePossibleCombination =

     0     0
     0     0


addOnes =

     1


onePossibleCombination =

     1     0
     0     0


addOnes =

     2


onePossibleCombination =

     0     0
     1     0


addOnes =

     3


onePossibleCombination =

     0     1
     0     0


addOnes =

     4


onePossibleCombination =

     0     0
     0     1


addOnes =

     1     2


onePossibleCombination =

     1     0
     1     0


addOnes =

     1     3


onePossibleCombination =

     1     1
     0     0


addOnes =

     1     4


onePossibleCombination =

     1     0
     0     1


addOnes =

     2     3


onePossibleCombination =

     0     1
     1     0


addOnes =

     2     4


onePossibleCombination =

     0     0
     1     1


addOnes =

     3     4


onePossibleCombination =

     0     1
     0     1


addOnes =

     1     2     3


onePossibleCombination =

     1     1
     1     0


addOnes =

     1     2     4


onePossibleCombination =

     1     0
     1     1


addOnes =

     1     3     4


onePossibleCombination =

     1     1
     0     1


addOnes =

     2     3     4


onePossibleCombination =

     0     1
     1     1


addOnes =

     1     2     3     4


onePossibleCombination =

     1     1
     1     1
```

How can we achieve that? All we need is to take all combinations taken by 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4. For that we use the `nchoosek` method as follows:

```
matrixSize = 2;
for k=0:matrixSize^2
  combinations=nchoosek(1:matrixSize^2,k);
  for m = 1:size(combinations,1)
    addOnes = combinations(m,:);
    onePossibleCombination = zeros(matrixSize,matrixSize);
    onePossibleCombination(addOnes) = 1;
    % Do your operation here with the matrix onePossibleCombination
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help Werner, that is exactly what I needed. I'd never heard of the addOnes command (I'm trying to teach myself MatLab).

Comment: @Jack There is no such command `addOnes`. The command I used is called `nchoosek`. `addOnes` is just a variable x), which, in fact, is only a column from the `combinations` variable that was the **output argument** from `nchoosek`.

Comment: @Jack don't forget to accept your answer and be welcome here.

Comment: @Jack not to mislead you, in fact it is a line from the combinations variable.